# How to get a list of main folders inside root directory in the S3 bucket? Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having a S3 bucket with folders and sub-folders containing files, I am trying to list all the folder names inside root directory. I dont want to list the sub-folders and files.

```
ex:
Test/Test1
Test/Test2
Test/Test3
Test/Test4
etc...
```

I have tried the following code which lists all the keys inside root directory

```
getListAllKeys(rootDirectory) {
    const containedEntities = {
      files: [],
      directories: []
    };
    const params = {
      Bucket: this.bucket,
      Prefix: Test/,
      Delimiter: Test/
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this._listAllKeys(
      resolve,
      reject,
      params,
      containedEntities
    ));
  }

  
  _listAllKeys(resolve, reject, params, containedEntities) {
    this.s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise()
      .then(({
        Contents, IsTruncated, NextContinuationToken,
      }) => {                   
        // filter files and directories
        Contents.forEach((item) => {
          containedEntities[item.Key.endsWith('/') ? 'directories' : 'files'].push(item);
        });
        // fetch further info if response is truncated
        if (IsTruncated) {
          this._listAllKeys(
            resolve,
            reject,
            Object.assign(params, { ContinuationToken: NextContinuationToken }),
            containedEntities
          );
        } else {
          resolve(containedEntities);
        }
      })
      .catch(reject);
  }
```

I am using AWS-SDK package. Please let me know how to list only the main folders

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain a list of directories, specify `Delimiter='/'` (with no Prefix specified).

A list of directories at the top (root) level will be returned in a list called `CommonPrefixes`.

It also works for sub-folders by specifying a Prefix.